# "have" or "has" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Should I use *have* or *has* in this sentence?

> The tree that grow in front of my house ______ (have or has) a big leaves.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Hi, Natalia. I recommend you spend some time looking over our [Contributor's Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners). There is a lot of information there about how to ask (and format) a question here on ELL.

Comment: The subject here is SINGULAR ***the tree***. So it's a tree ***that grows***, and ***that has** big leaves*. ***Grow*** and ***have*** are used for ***plural*** subjects.

Comment: English lacks an indefinite plural article so one would say "big leaves" and not "a big leaves".

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is *has*: A tree **has** leaves, but trees **have** leaves.

(If the subject is singular – like *tree* – we use *has*; if the subject is plural – like *trees* – we use *have*.)

There are quite a few other problems with your sentence, but we don't do proofreading here. Sorry, but I'm afraid you can't just post a sentence and ask us to find or correct errors. Questions that do that are normally promptly put on hold.